# Mysql left join, overwrite row only if field is_active = 1

Tags: mysql, join, union

9amI got help with the query from a previous post but I have a new question.
Bear with me in my explanation....

Setup, 2 tables: `cal_events` which holds dynamic events for a calendar and recurring events that have an update made to them for a single day. Also, `cal_events_recurring` which holds recurring events.
The query below is an example with dummy data that would be passed by PHP. 
I based it off of Dec 15th, so return every event for that day.
The important part is that the recurring event is only returned if it does not have a matching dynamic counterpart. If `cal_events`, `is_overwrite` = 1 and its `overwrite_id` = (the unique id of the 9:00 am `cal_events_recurring` event, then only return the dynamic table row.
This means, "Hey, I'm an event that occurs every day at 9:00am(example), but look, on Dec 15th the 9:00 recurring event has been updated for that day based on the dynamic table having my unique id = to its `overwrite_id` so return that one."

```
select * from(
    select
        ifnull(ce.time, cer.time) as time,
        ifnull(ce.title, cer.title) as title,
        ce.is_overwrite
    from cal_events_recurring cer
    left join cal_events ce on ce.overwrite_id = cer.id
    where cer.is_daily = 1
    or cer.day_index = 6
    or cer.day_num = 15
    union
    select time as time, title, is_overwrite 
    from cal_events where date = '2012-12-15' 
    and is_active = 1 and is_overwrite = 0) as e order by time asc
```

This is all well and fine, the data is correct, the problem is the `is_active` fields. 
I'll go off the 9:00am example again. I created a dynamic event for 9:00am for the 16th which will overwrite the recurring event on the 16th. Now if I later decide I want to revert back to the regular recurring event, I set the `is_active` field to 0 for the matching dynamic event. The problem is the dynamic event is still returned. If I add `and ce.is_active = 0` the event is still returned. How would I write it so that it would still return the recurring event if its dynamic counterpart is not active?

Any other info you need let me know!

EDIT*
output :

```
time      title 
08:00:00  recurring everyday 8am
09:00:00  dynamic 9am update 

(9am should be the recurring event because the dynamic    is_active = 0)
```

Comment: How does your expected output look like?

Comment: I added some output, as you can see the dynamic event is pulled still, even though it's is_active field = 0. It should pull the recurring event.

Comment: try an `inner join` and (probably) `union distinct`.

Comment: The problem is I still have to return all the recurring events that are not overwritten. If I did the inner join it would not return those, correct?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the first join went the other direction.  You'd need another union for inner join to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that condition into the `ON` clause:

```
select * from(
    select
        ifnull(ce.time, cer.time) as time,
        ifnull(ce.title, cer.title) as title,
        ce.is_overwrite
    from cal_events_recurring cer
    left join cal_events ce on ce.overwrite_id = cer.id
        and ce.is_overwrite = 1     -- Added this line
    where cer.is_daily = 1
    or cer.day_index = 6
    or cer.day_num = 15
    union
    select time as time, title, is_overwrite 
    from cal_events where date = '2012-12-15' 
    and is_active = 1 and is_overwrite = 0) as e order by time asc
)
```

Putting the special condition into the join condition means you still get a left join, but only for rows that should be joined.

If you put the condition in the where clause, you'll "break" the intention of the left join and the `ifnull()`, here's why:

Conditions in the `ON` clause of a join execute as the join is being made, so rows that you don't want joined don't get joined and don't make their values into the `ifnull()` function.

It is a common misconception that join conditions can only be "key related", when in fact they can be anything.

If you put the condition into the where clause, it is executed *after* the join is made - where clauses *filter* results sets, so it's too late - the `ifnull()` already has the dynamic table's data.

Comment: @Naterade np - I've edited the answer to provide some explanation. (btw, I followed your comment about another question from the previous question).

Comment: Wouldn't there need to be a date check to prevent other day one-time events from overwriting the specified recurring event?  Wouldn't there need to be an is_active check to prevent inactive daily events from over-riding active recurring events?